# C++ created multiple struct with class template

Tags: c++, template-specialization, template-classes

I want to create typesafe structures that are basically identical but have different types so that they require different function signatures.

```
struct A {
    Time t;
    void doStuff(const A&);
    A getStuff();
};

struct B {
    Time t;
    void doStuff(const B&);
    B getStuff();
};
```

If I sue a template for the class

```
template<class T>
struct X {
    Time t;
    void doStuff(const X&);
    X getStuff();
};
```

how can I make functions typesafe and define function signatures differently for a struct X of type A and a struct X of type B?

Comment: Your template looks wrong. You should write `doStuff(const X&);` and `X getStuff();`.

Comment: thanks. edited question

Comment: Another bug: What's the return type of `doStuff()`?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking.  The code you have is almost valid (except for the missing return type already mentioned, and some missing semicolons).  How do you want to use the types and/or the template, or what is it you want to add or change about them that you haven't shown?

Comment: @aschepler I think it's clear enough. The OP mentioned "typesafe" several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding some unused template parameters.

```
template <int>
struct X{
    Time t;
    void doStuff(const X&); // You missed return type
    X getStuff();
}; // You missed a semicolon

// Great thanks to "aschepler"
```

And now you can (C++11 syntax)

```
using A = X<1>;
using B = X<2>;
// typedef X<1> A;
// typedef X<2> B;
```

The following code will fail, which is what you want:

```
A a; B b;
a.doStuff(b); // Fail
a = b.getStuff(); // Fail
```

Comment: let me try that. curious, what do I need the second template for?

Comment: Ok, thanks, looking forward to give this a try later

Comment: It's entirely legal for a template definition to ignore any or all template parameters. (In fact, in that case you can even omit the parameter name, like `template <int> struct X {`...)

Comment: Good job, @aschepler . Now it's really type-safe.

Comment: @aschepler Now how can I define functions? `template <int> void X<???>::doStuff()` doesn't look so well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of Inheritance and template for that.
Following your line of thought, a possible code is:

```
template <class T> struct X {
    int time = 10;
    virtual void doStuff(const T&) = 0;
    virtual T getStuff() = 0;
};

struct A : X<A>
{
    void doStuff(const A& a) {
        cout << "Do A stuff" << endl;
    }

    A getStuff() {
        return *this;
    }
};

struct B : X<B>
{
    void doStuff(const B& value) {
        cout << "Do B stuff" << endl;
    }

    B getStuff() {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Then, testing we have:

```
int main()
{
    A a; B b;

    a.doStuff(a);  // Ok
    b.doStuff(b);  // Ok
    a.doStuff(b);  // fail
    b.doStuff(a);  // fail
    b = b.getStuff();  // Ok
    b = a.getStuff();  // fail

    return 0;
}
```